# How to correct the alignment (of the line numbers) in algorithmicx?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

How can I solve this alignment issue? I'm using the package `algorithmicx` and using following line for configuration.

```
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily\footnotesize}
```

[image: Alignment Issue]

However, removing that line, the alignment issue does also happen but it's only visible when looking carefully.

[image: Alignment Issue2]

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! If you post your complete code, then you are more likely to attract answers. ;) http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: Using precisely the command line you gave us `\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily\footnotesize}` I get an algorithm with [perfectly aligned line numbers](http://i.imgur.com/afgnBty.png). So there's something else causing the behavior. An MWE is definitely needed.